# Why is -replace not working as expected?

Tags: powershell, replace

In PowerShell I have the code

```
";10000;100;.0000" -replace ";.0000",";0.00"
```

and the result is : `";0.00;100;0.00"`

How is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-replace` uses regex. So that comes into play since you are looking for `;.0000` which has the regex special character `.` which matches *any* character. That is why there is a match at the beginning.

If you escape that period it is treated literally and you will get the expected results.

```psh
PS C:\Users\Matt> ";10000;100;.0000" -replace ";.0000",";0.00"
;0.00;100;0.00

PS C:\Users\Matt> ";10000;100;.0000" -replace ";\.0000",";0.00"
;10000;100;0.00
```

You can look at your example with a little more explanation at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yT7bK0/1).

> ; matches the character ; literally
>
> . matches any character (except newline)
>
> 0000 matches the characters 0000 literally

The above is taken from the linked resource.

So you either need to be aware of regex control characters (which is not a tough thing to get into) or if you are just doing basic search/replace you can also use the `.Replace()` string method which *does not* use regex.

```psh
PS C:\Users\Matt> ";10000;100;.0000".replace(";.0000",";0.00")
;10000;100;0.00
```

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I have an example already where the dot is escaped? Perhaps it was not made clear

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I don't even drink coffee so _all_ my reading is like that :)